# Why do I have such field names in my laravel project, despite all others are OK?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to configure simple laravel booking form for my project, but the names of fields are like this "quickadmin.bookings.fields.first_name*" but not like I want them to be, like this "first name".

I've tried to look through all files of project, where those forms could be configured, but due to lack of experience I can't find anything.

Here's some code from `create.blade.php` file

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
        {!! Form::label('first_name', trans('quickadmin.bookings.fields.first_name').'*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('first_name', old('first_name'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'required' => '']) !!}
        <p class="help-block"></p>
        @if($errors->has('first_name'))
        <p class="help-block">
            {{ $errors->first('first_name') }}
        </p>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the field to be named more common, like "First name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a field name but an item from the translation files. So you should have in the `resources/lang/en` (en, or whatever language you use) a `quickadmin.php` file that contains an array like this:

```
return [
    'bookings' => [
        'fields' => [
            'first_name' => 'First name'
        ]
    ]
];
```

If you want to simplify this, then remove some of the arrays.

And you get this `"quickadmin.bookings.fields.first_name*"` on the screen because the file and the array that I mentioned above are probably missing. So you can avoid that by creating what I just said, or create your own, just remember the first part is the filename, then it follows the items from the array.